# iOS - No Graphics when testing SK game on device

Tags: ios, debugging, ios-simulator, device

I have a problem with testing my SpriteKit game on my iPhone. 
In the simulator, it runs perfectly. But when I try to run the game on my device, there are no graphics. But the information in the corner right says that there are three nodes on the screen. When I touch an "invisible" node, the console prints that I touched it. 
I removed the game from my iPhone and built it again. But still the same problem. Cleaning it had also no effect.

Can someone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. 
I had to set the zPosition of my Sprite to a higher value than the background zPosition. I don't know why it worked on the simulator without setting the zPositions.

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation I could think of is when you put your pictures in Xcode you did not copy it to the project folder therefore it did not get bundled up in the IPA file and is unable to find the pictures on your phone. Remove the pictures and place them again ensuring that this time they get copied in the project folder.